# Best way to make the jump from programming to computer science

Tags: programming-languages, discrete-mathematics, software-engineering

I have decent enough experience with programming to be able to tackle most things but I want to know how you recommend making the jump from just programming to computer science. I still have a couple years till college, I'm only a sophomore right now although I am taking Calc over this summer which should help with some of the math of things. Are there any great books, authors or resources you recommend looking at? thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with time complexity and basic data structures? If not, I recommend you sign up for AP Computer Science. Time complexity isn't really focused on that much, but a good teacher will probably give a formal introduction into it.

Comment: Check out the CS degree of your local university and see if you can find the curriculum.  You'll probably find some courses on discrete mathematics (logic, combinatorics, graphs), algorithms and data structures, computation theory/complexity theory, etc.